# Scikit-learn classifier with custom scorer dependent on a training feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, grid-search

I am trying to train a RandomForestClassifier with a **custom scorer** whose output needs to be dependent on one of the features.

The **X** dataset contains 18 features:
[image: X dataset]

The **y** is the usual array of 0s and 1s:
[image: y_true]

The RandomForestClassifier with custom scorer is used within a GridSearchCV instance:
*GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid=[...], **scoring=custom_scorer**)*.

Custom scorer is defined via Scikit-learn function **make_scorer**:
*custom_scorer = **make_scorer**(custom_scorer_function, greater_is_better=True)*.

This framework is very straightforward if the custom_scorer_function is dependent only on *y_true* and *y_pred*. However in my case I need to define a scorer which makes use of one of the 18 features contained in the **X** dataset, i.e. depending on the values of *y_pred* and *y_true* the custom score will be a combination of them and the feature.

**My question is how can I pass the feature into the *custom_scorer_function* given that its standard signature accepts *y_true* and *y_pred*?**

I am aware it accepts extra **kwargs, but passing the entire feature array in this way doesn't solve the problem as this function is invoked for each couple of *y_true* and *y_pred* values (would need to extract the individual feature value corresponding to them to make this working, which I am not sure can be done).

I have tried to augment the *y_true* array packing that feature into it and unpacking it within the *custom_scorer_function* (1st column are the actual labels, 2nd columns are the feature values I need to calculate the custom scores):
[image: y_true_augmented]

However doing so violates the requirements of the classifier of having a 1D labels array and triggers the following error.

**ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'**

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: i am not sure why you want to pass it features....you can use weight or features importance to affect the score..\

Comment: Th problem is that the score uses the feature value I want to pass depending on the y_true and y_pred values, i.e. there will be 4 potential score values according to the cases y_true = y_pred = 0, y_true = 0 and y_pred = 1 and so on....

Comment: you should post your  code first, second,you can define features as global variable and access them in custom_score function

Comment: As @Eliethesaiyan says, just reference our global features data in the custom scorer. The order of the features and the labels should match,

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan,@Ken Syme
Passing the feature data as a global variable wouldn't work. In fact the custom_scorer function general signature is:

def custom_scorer(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs).

During training this gets invoked with y_true and y_pred (both scalars at each training step) to produce a score value. 
If I pass my feature data (let's say X[:, 10]) into the custom_scorer function as extra arg, this will be seen as an array within each training step. This would work if your custom score is something like (y_true - y_pred) * max(X[:, 10]), but that is not what I am after.

Comment: What I really need instead is a custom scorer that at each training iteration uses y_true, y_pred and the feature value extracted from the array X[:, 10] that actually corresponds to the selected y_true (same row in dataset terms).

So the question reduces to:

How can I define a custom scorer function that accepts a feature array (i.e. X[:, 10]) as extra arg and, at each training step (i.e. at each function call), is able to extract from it the value corresponding to the y_true?

Comment: @ClaudioN note that i didn't say you pass the features, make it a global variable so that it can be accessed by any function without being passed as variable. in that case you can pass the indexes of the batch, i beleive for each function call, the y_true, y_pred are related to the features passed to RandomCLassifier,if you pass 10 features values, of batch of features[i:i+10], you can pass, in **kwargs, make_score(y_pred,y_true,i,i+10): and select the feature(ie: feature2) you you want in features[i,i+10][2] inside make_score function since features is a global variable

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan
Once you define the custom scorer function, the custom scorer object to be passed to GridSearchCV is generally created as:

custom_scorer = make_scorer(custom_scorer_function, greater_is_better=True, extra_arg1=..., extra_arg2=... and so on)

with custom scorer function signature then being:

def custom_scorer_function(y_true, y_pred, extra_arg1, extra_arg2, ...)

So how exactly would you pass the index "i" as "extra arg" into it?

Comment: @ClaudioN, Have you solved this issue?. Accessing indices of the current fold in a custom score function for Gridsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (note you have given no real code so this is barebones)

```
X = [...]
y = [...]

def custom_scorer_function(y, y_pred, **kwargs):
   a_feature = X[:,1]
   # now have y, y_pred and the feature you want

custom_scorer = make_scorer(custom_scorer_function, greater_is_better=True)
...
```

Comment: This would not solve it. According to your code, in fact, at each training step (each call of the scorer) you will have a "scalar" y, a "scalar" y_pred and an "array" a_feature. That would work only if the custom score you want, as I said, depends on a global statistics of a_feature (for example (y - y_pred) * max(a_feature)). How would you pick "at each training step" the value from a_feature actually corresponding to the "scalar" y and the"scalar" y_pred?

Comment: @ClaudioN Are `y` and `y_pred` not arrays also when calling the scorer?

Comment: No! That's exactly the problem. The custom scorer is called behind the scene and at each step handles a couple of scalar values (Y-true and y_pred). I need to pass it also the scalar value taken from X[:, 10] that corresponds to those scalar, i.e. X[row, 10] where row is the index such that y_true = y[row].

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of scorers is they take the full array of train/test data so trying to work out where the scalers are coming from. What do you get when the only thing your custom scorer does is `print(y)` and `print(y_pred)`?

Comment: I did that. Got an error (obviously not a real scorer) but I actually got 2 arrays printed in the console so you might be right after all! Thanks for the heads up. I then passed the feature array into the custom scorer function as part of **kwargs and GridSearchCV seemed to proceed fine. However I got very weird values as gs.score(testX, testY), where gs is the GridSearchCV object and testX and testY represent the test datasets. Not sure the scorer is behaving as expected, but surely a step ahead!

Comment: If this helped can can you accept to close off the question? If you struggle with getting your scorer to work feel free to ask another question!

Comment: @ClaudioN, I am facing the same problem, basically, Gridsearch has cross-validation option (cv  3 by default), when it fits(X,Y), how can you access some features of X and you don't know the indices of the current fold?